# How can I handle collection data type? Because, I need save list account deposited to my pool and I have 5 BTreeMap

Tags: solana-program

- Im using write a program. In my program, I need save all account deposited SOL for my pool.
- I need 5 BTreeMap for all collection data in my program.
- Account size limit is 10MB. So, how can I handle collection data in my program.
- I need to be able to list all of the accounts (enumerate them)

Comment: If I'm understanding the question, you should be able to just create PDAs for each deposit. If you choose the right seeds, the accounts can be systematically derived one by one if all of the data is needed. For example, you could have one global account with a field called "deposit_index", which would be a Vec<u8> with incrementing numbers that are used as part of the seeds to derive the accounts

Comment: One important detail missing is whether you need to be able to list all of the accounts (enumerate them) or whether you _only_ require the ability to determine if a given account has made a deposit. Update your question with that detail and someone will be able to give you an answer.

Comment: I updated it, and I need to be able to list all of the accounts (enumerate them)